# software center "install" buttons greyed out

Tags: permissions, software-center, dpkg, steam

Running ubuntu 14.10 with software center 13.10 on my laptop.  All the install buttons are greyed out.  When I try to install stuff with apt-get I get the following error measage;

```
enduser@enduser-Latitude-E6400:~$ apt-get install {steam}
E: Could not open lock flie /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Any ideas? By the way I'm a total noob.

Answer (score 1):

The are you root? part shows that you do not have the privileges of installing new software. Try using `sudo` with your command to execute them as root user.

First run the command `sudo apt-get update` and then you can try to install the application with `sudo apt-get install app_name` where app_name is the application you want to install.